# Access denied when trying to show table in jsff fragment?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

Now I've started to split out parts into jsp fragments using f:subview

```
<af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr74">
        <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="100%" id="gc73" halign="stretch" columnSpan="5">
      <af:spacer id="sp19" height="10px"/>
            <af:declarativeComponent id="sp28" viewId="/pages/search/searchResult.jsff"/>
     </af:gridCell>
</af:gridRow>
```

The new jsff fragment (frontStoreSupport.jsff in this case) has it's own frontStoreSupportPageDef.xml which contains the binding entries I use in the page.

My problem is that ADF Read Only table's on this page get an "Access denied." where the content is supposed to go, despite the fact that they worked fine 
in the original page.

I've been into the Application > Security > Resource grants and added view to my application role, exactly like it was set up in the first page..

Any hints here would be greatly apprichiated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the answer by myself. Quit easy

Just need to copy the binding data generated in the table's fragment **pageDefinition** and paste  it into the **main** jsf page where you include the fragment as **declarativeComponent**